# Use of NUL character as delimiter on AWS S3 Object Select

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-s3-select

I'm trying to use S3 Select Object content to parse a CSV file that has NUL delimiter.

[image: Context of file]

The S3 API command I've tried is -

```sh
aws s3api select-object-content \
  --bucket "testbucket" \
  --key test.csv.gz \
  --expression "Select * from s3object s" \
  --expression-type 'SQL' \
  --input-serialization '{"CSV": {"FieldDelimiter": "'\0'", "FileHeaderInfo": "IGNORE"}, "CompressionType": "GZIP"}' \
  --output-serialization '{"CSV": {"FieldDelimiter": ","}}' test.csv
```

This does not seem to work and returns me

[image]

Is there any way to use NUL as delimiter for S3 Select Object Content?

Answer (score 0):

Using this command worked! :)

Thought it would be useful for someone

```sh
aws s3api select-object-content \
  --bucket "testbucket" \
  --key test.csv.gz \
  --expression "Select * from s3object s" \
  --expression-type 'SQL' \
  --input-serialization '{"CSV": {"FieldDelimiter": "", "FileHeaderInfo": "IGNORE"}, "CompressionType": "GZIP"}' \
  --output-serialization '{"CSV": {"FieldDelimiter": ","}}' test.csv
```